# Origin of "blue" for rude?

Tags: etymology, slang, colloquialisms

This question [Why do we talk a blue streak?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27452/why-do-we-talk-a-blue-streak), had me thinking—why do we use *blue* for rude ?

*Dictionary.com* has it: *lewd, indecent* recorded from 1840 "(in form *blueness*, in an essay of Carlyle's)" and a link to *[blue laws](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/blue%20laws)*, which means almost the exact opposite, but no origin.

<sup>Source: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/blue</sup>

Comment: THough I don't think this is relevant to your actual question, the 'blue' in 'blue streak' does not have the connotation/meaning of 'rude'. It just means 'fast' (as far as I know).

Comment: @Mitch, one of the answers mentioned "curse a blue streak" which does have - that's what made me think

Comment: I hadn't seen that question/answer yet. I disagree with that answer in that particular respect. The negativity in 'to curse a blue streak' comes from 'curse', not 'blue'.

Comment: @mitch, I think you're right "blue" is just the emphasis. Now - where does blue (as in blue movie) come from?

Comment: It seems the question has changed from "rude" to "obscene" (as shown on your comment and answer). Could you update the title and question body to reflect this?

Comment: [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=blue) suggests it could be obscure Scottish regional slang that Carlyle picked up. There doesn't seem to be a better suggetion.

Answer (score 6):

According to Green's *Dictionary of Slang*, in the eighteenth century itinerant Parisian booksellers covered their seditious or obscene material with blue paper; the first citation for *blue* meaning obscene comes from 1818.

Farmer and Henley note the French *Bibliotheque Bleu*, a series of books "of very questionable character", although they also suggest it may be derived from the "blue dress of harlots", which seems to me somewhat less likely.

Comment: "Bibliothèque Bleue" just means popular paperbacks (ie. pulp fiction), it doesn't imply rude. And the idea that rude books would be printed on blue paper is a bit of a stretch. I suppose the whole French = exotic and erotic, therefore all French literature = rude could be an explanation. Like the 70s idea that all of Sweden is in the porn business!

Comment: @Martin Beckett -- the 70s idea was that all of the porn business was in Sweden, not the other way around, which because of the laws at the time, wasn't far from true.  Remember *Splash*, John Candy was pretending to be from the "Swedish Institute" and all he knew how to say was "Hej, älskling, jag har en tolv-tums penis" ?

Comment: This answer should be disregarded. From OED: *A suggested connection with French bibliothèque bleue , denoting literature in a blue paper cover sold by itinerant sellers from the 17th to the 19th centuries and read by the lower social classes, seems unlikely, since such material appears in general to have been highly moral in tone.*

Answer (score 0):

I have read that 'Blue' is from early striptease or lewd theatre in London. Girls could be on stage naked, provided they were lit by blue lighting, which diminished any sense of movement.

Comment: This would be better if you could include a reference source for this.

Comment: Hi Simon, welcome to EL&U. Note that this site is a bit different from other Q&A sites: an answer here is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct* - preferably by citing published evidence in support of your proposition. You can [edit] your post to add this detail; for further guidance, see [answer]. Make sure you also take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Answer (score -2):

From Kliph Nesteroff’s *The Comedians* (2015), in reference to early 20th century vaudeville:

The phrase “working blue” came into usage at the time. If a representative of the Keith Orpheum circuit objected to the content of an act, a request to cut the material was sent backstage in a blue envelope. So-called blue material was considered problematic enough that vaudeville listings in local papers noted which shows were “Clean Bills.”

Comment: This is unlikely to be so as The Orpheum Circuit was a chain of American vaudeville and movie theaters was founded in 1886, yet the first recorded use of "blue" in this sense is in a British magazine "Sporting Life" in 1890: "Shifter wondered whether the damsel knew any novel blue stories."